# Can I store Jquery Cycle parameters in a variable?

Tags: jquery, cycle

Is it possible to store Jquery cycle parameters as a variable? The code below doesn't work and I'm trying to find out why.

```
var show=$(fx: 'fade', pause: 1, prev: '.prev', next: '.next');


$('.wrapper a.showOn').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
  $('#box-one div').fadeToggle('slow');
  $('#stage-one').cycle({show});
  $('#stage-one').cycle('pause');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var show = {
    fx: 'fade', 
    pause: 1, 
    prev: '.prev', 
    next: '.next'
};

$('#stage-one').cycle(show);
```

Comment: @claudie If it worked, feel free to click the green checkmark under the `downvote arrow` on the left to mark this question as answered.